# Ubuntu does not start after installing!

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I tried to install ubuntu 18.04 on my HP pavillion x 360 alongside with windows. 
After installing I restarted the laptop but no grub menu showed up. Then on windows when I checked disk management, the partitions on which I installed ubuntu were unallocated. Even in BIOS Boot Manager there was no option for ubuntu. I installed ubuntu via USB drive and used usb tethering for internet as the wifi adapter in my laptop is not compatible with ubuntu.

Fast Startup is turned off.

Secure Boot is turned off.

Comment: Did you see any error messages ?

Answer (score 0):

Try formatting the area that is being shown as unallocated (that you think you installed Ubuntu upon) in Windows disk management. Details for it are available online. Then reinstall the Ubuntu with a fresh ISO image. Remember to switch the boot sequence in Boot Menu before proceeding.